# Wordpress twenty eleven logo

Tags: wordpress, graphical-logo

I'm sure this has been asked many times, but how do you add a logo to the left of the site title on the Twenty Eleven child theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to navigate to the WordPress Twenty Eleven Theme folder in your WordPress installation at the following location:

`/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven`

Next open up the file called `header.php` and find the part that says `<h1 id="site-title">`. Finally, add your logo image before this along with anything else you may want.

Bare in mind you may need to use some CSS, like `display: inline;` for example to get it to sit on the same line as the text.

Answer (score 1):

Put your logo image in theme folder images folder. And then go and set the logo image in the header.php  as follow.

```
  <img src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="logo_image"  />
```

and adjust some css.
Done!  :)